Как можно обновить refresh_token в Spring Authorization Server?
Я следовал этому руководству https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/getting-started.html, чтобы внедрить токены доступа в своё веб-приложение, и всё работает нормально. Однако в этом руководстве ничего не говорится как обновить refresh_token.
Может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне реализовать это в Java Spring Boot? Есть ли способ обновить refresh_token, если уже была выдана пара токенов (refresh_token и access_token)?
